# LWR Community missing Content Management / Topic Assignment

Tags: community, digital-experience

I'm basically reworking an old Aura community using the new LWR framework. Its a website used for support articles.

Aura communities used to have a content management tab in the workspace builder where you could define Topics and assign articles with topics (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_topics_content.htm&type=5).

Now with LWR there is no such thing at all. There is no content management tab and I'm wondering if anyone has any information on how we are supposed to handle the topics with the new framework or should I entirely stop using them and move to using article categories?

Comment: While not an answer to your question, you might find https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/article/Salesforce-Knowledge-or-Salesforce-CMS-When-to-Use-Which helpful

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Salesforce recommends to use custom objects and to migrate the topics and topics assignments to them according to this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exp_cloud_migrate_lwr_considerations.htm&type=5